# How do I send a post request with axios? (CountriesNow API)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get the cities from Romania using the countriesnow api, however, I am always receiving the following message:
`{"error":true,"msg":"missing param (country)"}`
I've followed the [documentation](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1134062/T1LJjU52?version=latest#4829d16f-0f4e-43ec-886e-68ebad1221d8) for axios, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
var data = '{\n    "country": "romania"\n}';

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        headers: {},
        url: 'https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/cities',
        data: data
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

It however works with postman:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {
  country: "romania"
};
```

And the same to all.

If it doesn't work for you, I suggest to append the data to form data like the following.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('country','romania');

// same
```

Please refer to this.
[https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/axios-multi-form-data#:~:text=To%20send%20multipart%20form%20data,using%20the%20append()%20method](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/axios-multi-form-data#:%7E:text=To%20send%20multipart%20form%20data,using%20the%20append()%20method).

Comment: The first suggestion worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Diana Glad that helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the data as a JavaScript object instead of a JSON string.

```
    var data = {"country": "romania"};

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        headers: {},
        url: 'https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/cities',
        data: data
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```